# admin toolbar not showing sub-navi in Firefox any more

Tags: toolbar

First the admin toolbar worked perfectly fine in Mac-OS-FF – then suddenly the sub-navigation (the fly-out sub-pages) stopped showing – partly. The sub-navigation seems to be covered or cut off:

[image]

At that time I neither updated FF nor added/removed any browser-plugins or dp-modules. The same happened to three different dp7 installations simultaneously. I then updated FF – no change.

In chrome everything works fine.

Has anybody else witnessed similar behavior? 
Any pointers / tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in the [admin menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module. I think it was fixed in the latest stable version (if not in stable, then in dev). Try updating to the latest stable version of admin menu (currently 7.x-3.0-rc5).